# When to use $sth->fetchrow_hashref, $sth->fetchrow_arrayref and $sth->fetchrow_array?

Tags: perl, dbi

I know that:

- `$sth->fetchrow_hashref` returns a hashref of the fetched row from database,
- `$sth->fetchrow_arrayref` returns an arrayref of the fetched row from database, and
- `$sth->fetchrow_array` returns an array of the fetched row from database.

But I want to know best practices about these. When should we use fetchrow_hashref and when should we use fetchrow_arrayref and when should we use fetchrow_array?

Answer (score 13):

When I wrote YAORM for $work, I benchmarked all of these in our environment (MySQL) and found that arrayref performed the same as array, and hashref was *much* slower. So I agree, it is best to use array* whenever possible; it helps to sugar your application to know which column names it is dealing with. Also the fewer columns you fetch the better, so avoid `SELECT *` statements as much as you can - go directly for `SELECT <just the field I want>`.

But this only applies to enterprise applications. If you are doing something that is not time-critical, go for whichever form presents the data in a format you can most easily work with. Remember, until you start refining your application, efficiency is what is fastest for the *programmer*, not for the machine. It takes many millions of executions of your application to start saving more time than you spent writing the code.

Comment: +1 for benchmarking before making assertions about performance.

Answer (score 4):

DBI has to do more work to present the result as a hashref than it does as an arrayref or as an array.  If the utmost in efficiency is an issue, you will more likely use the arrayref or array.  Whether this is really measurable is perhaps more debatable.

There might be an even more marginal performance difference between the array and the arrayref.

If you will find it easier to refer to the columns by name, then use the hashref; if using numbers is OK, then either of the array notations is fine.

If the first thing you're going to do is return the value from the fetching function, or pass it onto some other function, then the references may be more sensible.

Overall, there isn't any strong reason to use one over the other.  The gotcha highlighted by [Ed Guiness](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4200/ed-guiness) can be decisive if you are not in charge of the SQL.

Answer (score 3):

You could do worse than read [DBI recipes](http://perlmonks.org/?node_id=284436) by [gmax](http://perlmonks.org/?node_id=127116).

It notes, among other things:

> The problem arises when your result
>   set, by mean of a JOIN, has one or
>   more columns with the same name. In
>   this case, an arrayref will report all
>   the columns without even noticing that
>   a problem was there, while a hashref
>   will lose the additional columns

Comment: On the other hand, the pitfall with using an array in conjunction with something like a 'select * from table where id = "blah"' means that you're at the mercy of the database and the order of the tables in it. Something as simple as a DBA adding a new column in the middle of the table will shift your array around, while a hashref will ignore it.

Answer (score 2):

In general, I use `fetchrow_hashref` (I get around two columns with the same name issue by using alias in the SQL), but I fall back to `fetch` (AKA `fetchrow_arrayref`) if I need it to be faster.  I believe that `fetchrow_array` is there for people who don't know how to work with references.

Comment: fetchrow_array() is also useful if you are selecting only _one_ column, in which case while ( my $whatever = $sth->fetchrow_array ) { say $whatever } DWIMs

Answer (score 1):

I don't use any of them since switching all of my DB code to use [DBIx::Class](http://search.cpan.org/dist/DBIx-Class/).